# Delta - Query - Latest data divided by Average of previous data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query in sql where latest datetime - Value gets divided by the previous average of Value over datetime so i can get the delta.

Kindly help thanks .

[image: My table]

Comment: Pls see the following guidance on asking good sql related questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query As it stands, this question is unlikely to be well received because it is just a call for full code.

Comment: That'll fail for the first record.

Comment: Kindly share the expected output

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you are looking for a query which will take average of column `Value` except `max(Time)` and divide the resultant by `Value` of `max(Time)`.

```
select (select Value from table1 t where t.time1 = (select max(time1) from table1)) / avg(Value) as Result
from table1 t
where t.time1 <> (select max(time1) from table1);
```

**Result:**

```
+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
| 4.1126 |
+--------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MCWM78892)**

Answer (score 0):

In the data that you provide, I notice two things:

1. The values are never repeated.
2. The values are strictly increasing.

If this is true in your data as a whole, then you can handle the calculation as:

```
select max(value) / ( ( sum(value) - max(value) ) / (count(*) - 1.0 ) )
from table1 t
```